# VB code for outlooks attachment to send secure

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I know nothing about VB.  I have the following code to have a reminder pop up if the word "attachment" is mentioned in the message body.  What I want is a reminder if the message includes an attachment and ask if the message should be sent securely (encrypted).

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
‘ Pops up a reminder if the word “attach” is found but there is no attachment on your email.
Dim m As Variant
Dim strBody As String
Dim intIn As Long
Dim intAttachCount As Integer, intStandardAttachCount As Integer

On Error GoTo handleError

‘Edit the following line if you have a signature on your email that includes images or other files. Make intStandardAttachCount equal the number of files in your signature.
intStandardAttachCount = 0

strBody = LCase(Item.Body)

intIn = InStr(1, strBody, “original message”)

If intIn = 0 Then intIn = Len(strBody)

intIn = InStr(1, Left(strBody, intIn), “attachment”)

intAttachCount = Item.Attachments.Count

If intIn > 0 And intAttachCount <= intStandardAttachCount Then

m = MsgBox(“It appears that you mean to send an attachment,” & vbCrLf & “but there is no attachment to this message.” & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & “Do you still want to send?”, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)

If m = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End If

handleError:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox “Outlook Attachment Reminder Error: ” & Err.Description, vbExclamation, “Outlook Attachment Reminder Error”
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: i know nothing about vb, can you help edit the code.

Comment: We will not write your code for you.  You should learn VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Mihn, I wanted to post this as a comment but then it wouldn't support so many characters.

SLaks is correct in saying that you should learn VBA :)

**TWO MAIN ADVANTAGES:**

**1)** You learn a new language

**2)** Tomorrow if you get stuck then you can make the edits yourself rather than asking for help again. This will also ensure that you will not have to wait endless hours for a solution

The code that you are using, I believe was written originally by Dan Evans which checks for the word "attachement" in the `.Subject` and the `.Body` of the email and serves a different purpose as you have rightly mentioned above.

For your query, see the below.

**HINT**

Use the `item.Attachments.Count` to see if there are attachments as shown in your code above and then simply encrypt the message.

**CAUTION**

Encrypting attachments is not a simple process. It is slightly advanced than normal VBA code. So be prepared for lots of learning ;)

Give it a try and if you are stuck then simply post the code that you tried and we will definitely help you (i.e if you show efforts in learning the language) :)

HTH

Sid